# How to make left-most flex item stay fixed to screen and other flex items move right and overflow right when screen size reduced?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am creating a responsive front page with articles that resize with the page.  I have a div 'flex-container' which will contain 3 or 4 articles, maybe more.  If the page is increased in size, the articles spread out, and if the page is reduced in size they get pushed together and overlap slightly and the user can scroll right to see the articles on a screen.

I want the left side of the 'flex-continainer' div to stay pinned to the left side of the screen and only the right hand side of it to flow off the right hand side of the screen, so the first article is always visible and the user has to scroll right to see the rest.  I am having difficulty doing this and making the scroll bar appear properly. As the screen is reduced in size, the center of the 'flex-container' div remains in the center of the screen, and the articles overflow off the left and right hand side of the screen. So the left hand side of the first article is not visible.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.article {
  display: flex;
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  border: solid 4px white;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgb(77, 74, 74));
  box-shadow: -10px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.article:hover {
  z-index: 1;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="article">
    <h2>Heading 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <h2>Heading 3</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to nikola pavicevia and biberman. Your answers didn't quite work for me but helped me get to a solution.  The desired behaviour can be achieved with setting justify-content to flex-start and padding left to 50px on the flex container and margin-right to auto on the articles.

```css
.flex-container{
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    padding-left:50px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    background-color: grey;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.article{
    display: flex;
    width: 30%;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-right:auto;
    border: solid 4px white;
    border-radius: 16px;
    background: linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgb(77, 74, 74));
    box-shadow: -10px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index: 0;
}

.article:hover{
    z-index: 1;
}

h2{
    font-size: 2.5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="article">
        <h2>Heading 1</h2>
    </div>
    
    <div class="article">
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    </div>
    
    <div class="article">
        <h2>Heading 3</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you set `margin-right` for the first article to `0` and omit `justify-content` for the container you will get the desired result.

**Working example:**

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.article {
  display: flex;
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  border: solid 4px white;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgb(77, 74, 74));
  box-shadow: -10px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.article:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.article:hover {
  z-index: 1;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="article">
    <h2>Heading 1</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="article">
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="article">
    <h2>Heading 3</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```